# MVVM - How to pass an already existing ViewModel to a new View to be databound

Tags: c#, mvvm, mvvm-light

this is my scenary: in a MainPage I show a list of Details. So I have created some DetailViewModels which are organized in the MainViewModel in an ObservableCollection.

I want to open a DetailPage by clicking one item in the list of Details. So I navigate to DetailPage. And now I want to use the already existing DetailViewModel (just clicked) to be bound to the DetailPage. I don't know how to do that - although it seams to be a quite common situation. Using default MVVM Light there is a new DetailViewModel instance created.

Probably I am just missing something...

Thanks

Hans-Peter

Answer (score 0):

In short, change your setup

A `ViewModel` gathers all `Models` (which contain the data) to be displayed, but does not contain the data **itself**. So in your case, the `DetailViewModel` should only exist once in your application, but it may contain a `DetailModel` with the actual data you want to display.

You can use the `Messenger` to pass the selected `DetailModel` from the `MainViewModel` to the `DetailViewModel` once it is constructed, or create a `SelectDetailModel(DetailModel model)` method in your `DetailViewModel` which you set once a new `DetailModel` is selected

```
SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<DetailViewModel>().SelectDetailModel(model);
```